# How to resize boot partition on ubuntu 14.10 using gparted

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I have **Ubuntu 14.10** installed on my pc of 500GB HDD. I created a seperate **boot partition** and now its running low on space while upgrading to 15.04. I even tried cleaning out spaces, still its not enough. How to add more space to boot partition from root partition using **gparted**?

Comment: You should be able to just unalloacate space from your existing partitions then extend the boot partition.  The problem you will run into is you have to have continous space.  So the best solution is to repartition the entire drive

Comment: I don’t have unallocated space, I have space in root partition.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-size boot if you had contiguous space but i'm guess you don't since root file system was probably directly after boot.

You can create a new boot partition and format it, copy all the contents of the existing boot partition to the new partition, mark it bootable, and resetup the grub bootloader.  Something like this guide:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition

Once you have that partition created, you would delete the old boot partition.  Before any of this work is done though, I highly recommend you backup the drive incase you need to get back.

EDIT: Also, you should have enough to upgrade ubuntu.  I'm gonig to guess that you need to remove some old kernels?  You only need the latest one.   you can do this to remove them

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: Can't I just resize root partition removing some space next to boot, and add it to boot partition?

Comment: This is weird. You can expand your boot partition into unallocated space in OS X and even in Windows, but I can't find a way to do it on a Linux system (at least not with gparted).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming boot is first partition (left in gparted window) and root is second (right in gparted window).
Using gparted, you can reduce the size of root (select partition and hit resize button), move it to the right (move button) and then resize boot (select partition and hit resize button).